# Spring MVC returning Data into Multiselect listbox

Tags: java, spring-mvc, data-binding, multi-select

I have two html list boxes which i am populating from the database a single select box and a multi select box. I am unable to return a list object into the multi select list box instead i am getting an error. Under is my code:

**listbox 1**

This gets sets and gets data fine:

```
<form:select path=""
id="dbvictims" title="Victims Of Crime" class="victimLst">
<form:options items="${dbvictims.dbvictimList}"
itemValue="socialSecurityNumber" itemLabel="name" />
</form:select>
```

**Second list box (multiselect)**

```
<form:select
path="victims" id="victims" title="Victims Of Crime"
multiple="multiple" class="victimLst">
<form:options items="${victimList}"
itemValue="socialSecurityNumber" itemLabel="name" />
</form:select>
```

**Jdbc**

Both listboxes use the same jdbc function to get their data
I places a message inside List getVictimList() and its not even getting into the function the second time. When the page is GET it accesses the function when it is returned form the server before the view is displayed the function is accessed again to show set data in the second list. Even if the function is separate the same issue still arises.

```
 public List<Citizens> getVictimList() throws Exception{
        String sql ="SELECT socialSecurityNumber,UCASE(CONCAT(fname ,CONCAT(' ', lname)))as name FROM TBLCITIZENS WHERE citizenTypeId = 3";//victims - 3

        List<Citizens> victimList = new ArrayList<Citizens>();

        List<Map<String, Object>> rows = getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(sql);
        for(Map<String, Object> row :rows){
            Citizens acitizen = new Citizens();
            acitizen.setName((String)row.get("name"));
            acitizen.setSocialSecurityNumber((Integer)row.get("socialSecurityNumber"));
            victimList.add(acitizen);
        }
        return victimList;
    }
```

**Controller:**

If the second list box is set using myVictimList instance variable the html does not get rendered and page is blank.

```
myVictimList.put("dbvictimList",this.citizenManager.getListOfVictims());

Map<String, Object> myVictimList = new HashMap<String, Object>();

//this gets set in a GET function - code above ist list box gets set before the second. The second gets set when return from the server after a POST

model.addAttribute("dbvictims", myVictimList);

model.addAttribute("victimList",this.crimeManager.getVictimList());

return new ModelAndView("crime_registration");
```

**Error:**

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:972)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError    com.crimetrack.service.CrimeManager.getVictimList(CrimeManager.java:47)     com.crimetrack.service.CrimeManager.getVictimList(CrimeManager.java:47)     com.crimetrack.service.CrimeManager.getVictimList(CrimeManager.java:47) ........
19236 [http-bio-8084-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext  - Publishing event in WebApplicationContext for namespace 'crimetrack-servlet': ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/crimeTrack/getCrime/8.htm]; client=[127.0.0.1]; method=[POST]; servlet=[crimetrack]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[156ms]; status=[failed: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError]
19236 [http-bio-8084-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext  - Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/crimeTrack/getCrime/8.htm]; client=[127.0.0.1]; method=[POST]; servlet=[crimetrack]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[156ms]; status=[failed: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError]
```

**Firebug**

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost:8084/crimeTrack/getCrime/8.htm"
```